# Python, html and flask

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I am in a very basic level of programming and I am trying to make a table were I can select options via radio buttons and put quantities for each row of the table.
Then, at my back end (python) I want to get the values of the radio buttons and the quantity of each row.  But the name of my radio buttons is a variable and is different for each row.  How can I get the value from the button in python.
Here is my html: 
[This is how my page looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbd4c.png)

Thanks !

Comment: The best way to get your answer is to post some code we can look at and identify exactly where you're stuck and which part is not working. There is no possible way anyone can answer your question without more information from you. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please share your code. Otherwise, all we can do is point you toward tutorials.

Comment: This is the code to the front end: <script src="https://pastebin.com/embed_js/3HVzHFWS"></script> 
I am using python in the back end.  I get the forms by request.form.get("symbol"), where "symbol" is the name of the element.  But I can only get 1 value and I need to get a list of elements.